# Spring Boot Security: Access to new PDF

Tags: java, spring, pdf, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm developing an application where I need to fill pdf forms with data from the view. Before I set Spring Boot Security, everything was working fine.

The folder where I create this PDFs is set as public. When I start the application, I can access to all PDFs created before the start, but when I create a new one (and I can open the file on my file system and checked it was created correctly) the request for this file gives me a 404 not found answer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serve your pdfs as `static` resources. Register pdf directory via Spring boot.

The following configuration registers `pdf` mime type and configures static resources.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

/**
 * Set up Mime types.
 */
@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
    // IE issue, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/711
    mappings.add("html", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
    // CloudFoundry issue, see https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/issues/64
    mappings.add("json", "text/html;charset=utf-8");

    mappings.add("pdf", "application/pdf");

    container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
}

  ....
}

// Register static resources
@Configuration
public class AppMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  // Including all static resources.

  registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**", 
              "/css/**", 
              "/img/**",
              "/js/**",
              "/pdf/**"
         ).addResourceLocations("/assets/",
              "/css/", 
              "/img/",
              "/js/",
              "/pdf/**"
  ).resourceChain(true)
   .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());

   super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
```

}
}

Comment: Thanks Anton for your answer. The problem was the server, not the settings. When I created a file I was trying to send the url to the view, and as the file didn't exist when the server started, So now instead of sendig the url I send the complete file using HttpServlet response.